# C++ Boost usage over a string

Tags: c++, boost

I have no idea about boost, could anybody please tell me what exactly this function is doing?

```
int
Function(const string& tempStr)
{
    boost::regex expression ("result = ");
    std::string::const_iterator start, end;
    start = tempStr.begin();
    end   = tempStr.end();
    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
    boost::regex_constants::_match_flags flags = boost::match_default;
    int count = 0;
    while(regex_search(start, end, what, expression, flags)){
        start = what[0].second;
        count++;
    }
    cout << "Count :"<< count << endl;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: On a side note, using regex for that is overkill as this could simply be done using `std::string::find()`, which would achieve better performance.

Answer (score 2):

[match_results](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_results.html) is a collection of `sub_match` objects. The first `sub_match` object (index 0) represents the full match in the target sequence (subsequent matches would correspond to the subexpressions matches). Your code is searching for `result =` matches and restarting the search each time from the end of the previous match (`what[0].second`)

```
int
Function(const string& tempStr)
{
    boost::regex expression ("result = ");
    std::string::const_iterator start, end;
    start = tempStr.begin();
    end   = tempStr.end();
    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
    boost::regex_constants::_match_flags flags = boost::match_default;
    int count = 0;
    while(regex_search(start, end, what, expression, flags)){
        start = what[0].second;
        count++;
    }
    cout << "Count :"<< count << endl;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    Function("result = 22, result = 33"); // Outputs 'Count: 2'
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6be0ec02caf3826)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The base of the functionality is searching for a regular expression match on `tempStr`.

Look at the [regex_search](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) documentation and notice what the match_result contains after it finishes (that's the 3rd parameter, or `what` in your code sample). From there understanding the `while` loop should be straightforward.

Comment: If possible, could you please explain with an example?

Comment: Why don't you just run a simple test? @Marco's answer includes one

Answer (score 0):

This function is a complicated way to count the number of occurrences of `"result = "` string. A simpler way would be:

```
boost::regex search_string("result = ");
auto begin = boost::make_regex_iterator(tempStr, search_string);
int count = std::distance(begin, {});
```

Which can be collapsed to a one-liner, with possible loss of readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is a match counter function:

The author uses useless code: here is the equivalent code in std ( also boost )

```
unsigned int count_match( std::string user_string, const std::string& user_pattern ){

    const std::regex rx( user_pattern );

    std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::const_iterator > first( user_string. begin(), user_string.end(), rx  ), last;

    return std::distance( first, last );

}
```

and with `std::regex_search` it can be (also boost ):

```
unsigned int match_count( std::string user_string, const std::string& user_pattern ){
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > match_result;

    std::regex regex( user_pattern );

    while( std::regex_search( user_string, match_result, regex ) ){
        user_string = match_result.suffix().str();
        ++counter;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

---

NOTE:
no need to use this part:

```
std::string::const_iterator start, end;
start = tempStr.begin();
end   = tempStr.end();
```

Also

```
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
```

can be

```
boost::smatch what // a typedef of match_results<std::string::const_iterator>
```

no need:

```
boost::regex_constants::_match_flags flags = boost::match_default;
```

because by default `regex_search` has this flag

this:

```
start = what[0].second;
```

is for updating the iteration that can be:

```
match_result.suffix().str();
```

---

if you want to see what happen in the while loop use this code:

```
std::cout << "prefix: '" << what.prefix().str() << '\n';
std::cout << "match : '" << what.str() << '\n';
std::cout << "suffix: '" << what.suffix().str() << '\n';
std::cout << "------------------------------\n";
```